# mapping Field with variable type using Hibernate Annotaion

Tags: java, hibernate

how can I have a field with variable type in my class? I use hibernate annotation for mapping to DB. I tried to use java.io.Serializable as field's type, but it mapped to database as a 01 amount which is true if I get it's object and cast it to it's true type. but I need to run a query on this objects that needs true amount of field.(right now I can't compare an integer field with a number) 
Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have variable types in Java - it is [*statically typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language) language.

I guess you can achieve something like this with [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) (+ [grails](http://www.grails.org/)), which is [*dynamically typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language). Using something like `def someField` you can later use `someField` as whatever you expect it to be.